# Nested Packages

Tags: perl, perl-module

Sorry for the base question, but how can I nest Packages/Modules in Perl? I am writing a Sudoku solver to become used to Perl and I would like to logical divide my code into pieces:

```
Piece 1: Utils
Piece 2: Main logic
```

but when I try to do something  like this :

```
package Sudoku::Utils; 
. 
.
. Util code
.
.
1;
```

What should I name this file ? I tried Util.pm, but when I tried to import it, Eclipse threw an error.

```
package Sudoku; 
.
.
. Main logic code
.
.
.
```

Any ideas on how to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `package Sudoku::Utils;` ⇒ in `Sudoku/Utils.pm` file ⇒ `use Sudoku::Utils;`
- `package Sudoku;` ⇒ in `Sudoku.pm` file ⇒ `use Soduku;`

Comment: Do I need to import Sudoku::Utils into package Sudoku inside of Sudoku.pm? Or is it there implicitly ?

Comment: The packages are completely independent; `Soduku::Utils` has no particular knowledge of `Soduku` and vice-versa. If you want to load and import `Soduku::Utils`, you must `use` it.

Comment: yes, you need to use "use the_package_needed;". No implicit import is done

Comment: Ok, from inside of the Sudoku.pm file, when I `use Sudoku::Utils;` eclipse can't seem to locate it, even though it is in the same directory.

Comment: In the project settings, add `${proj_loc}` to the dircetories to search for modules. (At least, I think that's how it's spelled.)

Comment: @ikegami In the Path Variables section of the project properties, PROJECT_LOC is already listed and is pointing to the correct directory.

Comment: You're not in the right spot, cause teh syntax is definitely `${...something...}`

Comment: [This screen](http://www.epic-ide.org/guide/ch03s02.php), and it's `${project_loc}`.

Comment: @ikegami Adding `${project_loc}` to that list didn't let Eclipse see the library. I had to add `use lib '../';` before `use Sudoku::Utils;` and that seems to work.